# Replace code based in string into code component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have String which includes code and i am rendering it like this

```
  <Typography
    variant='subtitle1'
    sx={{ mb: "10px", whiteSpace: "break-spaces" }}>
        {replaceCodeWithBlock(chat)}
  </Typography>
```

here is function to replace code with code component

````
// Function to replace code with code block component
const replaceCodeWithBlock = (chat) => {
    const codeRegex = /```(\w+)\n([\s\S]+?)\n```/g;
    const replacedChat = chat.replace(codeRegex, (match, language, code) => {
        return (
             <Paper
               sx={{
                 p: "18px",
                 borderRadius: "14px",
                 background: "rgba(223, 165, 16, 0.45)",
                 boxShadow: "none",
                 marginBottom: "10px",
               }}>
                 <code>{code}</code>
             </Paper>
        );
      });

      return replacedChat;
};



 var dynamicVariable = encodeURIComponent(router.query.topic).replace(
    /\+/g,
    "\\+\\+"
 );
 //replace this regex with paper
 var regex = new RegExp("```" + dynamicVariable, "g");
````

What i am looking for is when ever their is code string
i want to render inside of Paper component
[image]